# Validate input to ensure negative number

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to make code that asks the user to enter 10 numbers and subtracts them all. This is what i have so far. I think i have the general layout all set but i dont know what to do with the rest

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class subnumbs 
{ 
   int dial;
   int[] num = new int [10];
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   public void go()
   {
      int q=0;
      dial = 10;

      while (q != 0)
      {
         System.out.println("type numb: ");
         int newinput = scan.nextInt();
         q+=newInteger;
         dial = cdial + 1;
      } 
      return q;
   }
}
```

Comment: A very simple solution is to simply assume that the user *meant* to enter a negative number. In other words, if the input is positive, multiply with `-1`. Done. :)

Comment: If you really want to keep asking for negative numbers, however, I would suggest you simply split your program into two parts: first, getting the user input. Second, processing the input. This way, you can just make it so the first loop runs *until* you managed to get 10 negative values from the user. Once that's done, you break out of the loop and go to the second part.

Answer (score 0):

this is one way to ensure inly negative numbers, only count down and add it if it was negative ...

```
while (counter != 0)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");
         int newInteger = scan.nextInt();
             if(newInteger < 0) {
                 n+=newInteger;
                 counter -= 1; 
             }
             else {
                 System.out.println("must be negative integer, please try again:  ")
             {
      }
```

In general, to ensure an input you have to evaluate it at the point where you are getting the input

Comment: this is the exact way of what i'm looking for so thanks for that! only problem is it kinda seems not right by just countlessly saying "Enter Integer". Is there a way to display a different message to tell the user to enter a negative number when they haven't done so?

Comment: @B.Simmons ye, just write it in the "else" part of the statement, that will be executed everytime they did NOT enter a negative integer

Comment: OK i see but now when the integer is positive i ran it and it will says "Re-enter integer:" then immediatly jump back up and say "Enter Integer again". like it doesnt allow you to enter on "Re-enter Integer"

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printIn("Enter Integer: "); 
 int newInteger = scan.nextLine(); 
 While (newInteger >= 0){
     System.out.println("Re-enter Integer (must be negative): ");
     newInteger = scan.nextLine(); 
}

 n+=newInteger; 
 Counter = counter - 1;
  return n;
```